# React: Table custom sort doesn't sort when data is mixed with capital and small letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am trying to sort data using custom sort function in react. Unfortunately the function only sort items if the records are either capital letter or small letter. It doesn't sort the data with mixed capital and small letter properly. Here is the live [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-sorting-example-forked-7sfmhb?file=/src/App.js:0-2909)

Here is the code

```js
const useSortableData = (items, config = null) => {
  const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = React.useState(config);

  const sortedItems = React.useMemo(() => {
    let sortableItems = [...items];
    if (sortConfig !== null) {
      sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[sortConfig.key] < b[sortConfig.key]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (a[sortConfig.key] > b[sortConfig.key]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }
    return sortableItems;
  }, [items, sortConfig]);

  const requestSort = (key) => {
    let direction = 'ascending';
    if (
      sortConfig &&
      sortConfig.key === key &&
      sortConfig.direction === 'ascending'
    ) {
      direction = 'descending';
    }
    setSortConfig({ key, direction });
  };

  return { items: sortedItems, requestSort, sortConfig };
};

const ProductTable = (props) => {
  const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(props.products);
  const getClassNamesFor = (name) => {
    if (!sortConfig) {
      return;
    }
    return sortConfig.key === name ? sortConfig.direction : undefined;
  };
  return (
    <table>
      <caption>Products</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => requestSort('name')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('name')}
            >
              Name
            </button>
          </th>
          <th>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => requestSort('price')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('price')}
            >
              Price
            </button>
          </th>
          <th>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => requestSort('stock')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('stock')}
            >
              In Stock
            </button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <tr key={item.id}>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>${item.price}</td>
            <td>{item.stock}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ProductTable
        products={[
          { id: 1, name: 'Cheese', price: 4.9, stock: 20 },
          { id: 2, name: 'milk', price: 1.9, stock: 32 },
          { id: 3, name: 'Yoghurt', price: 2.4, stock: 12 },
          { id: 4, name: 'Heavy Cream', price: 3.9, stock: 9 },
          { id: 5, name: 'butter', price: 0.9, stock: 99 },
          { id: 6, name: 'Sour Cream ', price: 2.9, stock: 86 },
          { id: 7, name: 'Fancy French Cheese ', price: 99, stock: 12 },
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<App />);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead th {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

thead button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

thead button.ascending::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

thead button.descending::after {
  content: '☝️';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

tbody td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I have tried to change **a** and **b** to lowercase from **useSortable** but since there is **price** column with number, I got error.

What can I do to make it work regardless of case sensitivity.

Comment: using `toLowerCase` to sort strings should fix it, no? If you want to value lower and uppercase the same, just convert the strings to lowercase before you compare them (of course, keep the original string for rendering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the type, like:

```
if (typeof a[sortConfig.key] === "string" && typeof b[sortConfig.key] === "string") {
    if (a[sortConfig.key].toLowerCase() < b[sortConfig.key].toLowerCase()) {
      return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
    }
} else {
    if (a[sortConfig.key] < b[sortConfig.key]) {
      return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is reasonable to have different sorting functions for different types. I suggest having a sort function for string type and for number type and utilizing it according to the column type. That way code becomes more clear and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing 2 strings using `a[sortConfig.key] < b[sortConfig.key]` will cause the comparison to be made based on the character code point, not by the character contents. An easy way to compare 2 strings based on contents is by using [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

If you're positive that `a[sortConfig.key]` and `b[sortConfig.key]` will always return a string you can `return a[sortConfig.key].localeCompare(b[sortConfig.key])` without any additional checks.

However in your scenario they could also represent the `price` or `stock` which are numbers and therefore do not have the method `localeCompare()`. So we should check if both values are strings beforehand.

I personally don't like to type check, since JavaScript is a ducktyping language. I usually check if the method I need is available.

Assuming the following helper is defined:

```
function hasMethod(item, methodName) {
  // intentional != usage, checks for both null and undefined
  return item != null && typeof item[methodName] === "function";
}
```

You can sort your collection in the following manner:

```
const modifier = sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;

sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
  const [valueA, valueB] = [a, b].map(item => item[sortConfig.key]);
  const areLocaleComparable = [valueA, valueB].every(value => hasMethod(value, "localeCompare"));

  if (areLocaleComparable) return valueA.localeCompare(valueB) * modifier;

  return (-(valueA < valueB) || +(valueA > valueB)) * modifier;

  // or instead of the above line
  if (valueA < valueB) return -1 * modifier;
  if (valueA > valueB) return  1 * modifier;
  return 0;
});
```

Alternatively you could use `typeof value === "string"` instead of `hasMethod(value, "localeCompare")` if you rather use type checking.